# Some characters like vertical bar(|) or slash(/) is forced to be newline characters in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I noticed my issue that some characters like vertical bar(|) or slash(/) is forced to be newline characters in iOS7's `UILabel` / `UITextView`.

iOS7 screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3jfx.jpg
iOS6 screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X069.jpg

But in iOS6 like my iOS6's screenshot, my issue doesn't occur in `UILabel` / `UITextView`.

So is this a iOS7's bug? Or could I solve the issue?

Comment: What's the linke break mode?

Comment: Current line break mode is Character Wrap. However Word Wrap and Truncate Tail couldn't solve my issue.